# Python, Boolean - Conditionals & Control Flow - Not understanding

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-logic

I cant seem to grasp Bootlean operators. I'm using an example from Code Academy. At first I read it wrong and was putting `True or not False and False` Instead of `True or False`.

Can someone explain this a bit more clearly for me so I can get more of an understanding.

```
Assign True or False as appropriate for bool_one through bool_five.

Set bool_one equal to the result of False or not True and True
Set bool_two equal to the result of False and not True or True
Set bool_three equal to the result of True and not (False or False)
Set bool_four equal to the result of not not True or False and not True
Set bool_five equal to the result of False or not (True and True)
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: First apply Python's rules on operator precedence to add brackets so that the grouping of operations is visually clear. (The relevant rule here is that "and" has greater precedence than "or", i.e. "a and b or c" is equivalent to "(a and b) or c", not "a and (b or c)".) When you have done this, work out what the bracketed expressions evaluate to and then what the greater expression evaluates to.

Answer (score 1):

You have three boolean operations and some rules:

1. `not`, which just inverses (aka `not True` => `False`, `not False` => `True`)
2. `or`, which works on two operands `x or y` and returns `True` if either is `True` and `False` if they are both `False`
3. `and`, which works on two operands `x and y` and returns `True` if both are `True` and `False` otherwise
4. They are evaluated from left to right
5. `not` has the highest precedence, `and` after that, lastly `or`
6. You can use `()` to change the precedence of operations, just as in everyday math

Comment: Strictly speaking, `and` returns the first value if it is false, otherwise the second value;  `or` returns the first value if true, otherwise the second.  So `[] and 'abc'` returns `[]`, and `[] or 'abc'` returns `'abc'`, etc.

Comment: @augurar, true, but you will just confuse him more. Let him understand boolean calculus first.

Comment: @ndn - Thanks for correcting my code and the answer, appreciate the time you put into doing that

Answer (score 0):

[5.15 Operator Precendence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=precedence#operator-precedence) (listed lowest to highest, and I trimmed many operators)

> `or`
>   `and`
>   `not`
>   `(expressions...)`

So you can see that from low to high precedence it is `or` then `and` then `not` then `()`. Example

```
False or not True and True
```

So if I add parentheses to emphasize order

```
(False or (not True)) and (True)
```

becomes

```
(False or False) and (True)
False and True
False
```

You can follow this process with the other lines

Answer (score 0):

A boolean variable can have one of two values - `True` or `False`. There are several operators that can help you manipulate boolean values:

- `not` inverts the value - `True` becomes `False` and vise-versa
- `and` returns `True` if and only if both operands evaluate to `True`
- `or` returns `True` if either or the operands evaluate to `True`

This exercise asks you to translate the English statements to python:

```
bool_one = False or not True and True
bool_two = False and not True or True
bool_three = True and not (False or False)
bool_four = not not True or False and not True
bool_five = False or not (True and True)
```